# Combine __icontains lookup with __in lookup in django to get objects that contain part of name in names array

Tags: django, django-models, django-queryset

Hi My models are as follows

```
class Document(models.Model)
    id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True)
    text = models.TextField()

class DocumentTags(models.Model):
    name = model.CharField(max_length=256)
    documents_for_tag = models.ManyToManyField(Document)
```

Now with this I can get all the tags for a particular document with

```
parent_document = Document.objects.get(id = 1)
parent_document_tags = [x.name for x in parent_document.documenttags_set.all()]
```

So the `parent_document_tags` will have all the tags for the parent document for eg.

```
["nice" , "unique"]
```

Now I want to next get all the `Document`s that have tags that closely match this list of tags. I am doing this with

```
Document.objects.filter(documenttags__name__in=parent_document_tags).distinct()
```

This however matches only documents that have exactly the names in the `parent_document_tags`. I want to match with an `__icontains` (or `LIKE`) match. How do I do this without splitting up  my tags and doing an icontains type lookup one by one.

for eg.

```
d1 has tags : "nice", "unique"
d2 has tags :  "nice"
d3 has tags : "nicer"
```

I want the query to return document d3 as well with a `LIKE` match for "nicer" by chaining the `__icontains` onto the lookup `documenttags__name__in` . Can I achieve that or do I have to have a for loop and filter out the duplicates in the end like this code below

```
related_documents_with_duplicates = []
for tag in parent_document_tags:
    docs = Document.objects.filter(documenttags__name__icontains=tag).distinct()
    related_documents_with_duplicates.extend(docs)
related_documents_id_unique = list(set([x.id for x in related_documents_with_duplicates]))
return Documents.objects.filter(id__in=related_documents_id_unique)
```

Comment: I think it's too complex. Try to make it with raw SQL - i guess you'll need to use something specific to your DB.

Comment: I agree in that I dont like the readability of lookups like "documenttags__name__in"..but I am trying to learn django as I build this project and what to know what are the best ways of writing queries to minimize hits to the database

Comment: It's not only too complex to read but also too complex for ORM. I'm not sure if mysql or postgres can make such query.

Comment: On the other hand, you can make a query using Q(documenttags\_name\_\_like="str1") | Q(documenttags\_name\_\_like="str2") | ... Not sure if it will work fast enough but you can try.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/q/3923589/ and http://stackoverflow.com/q/9674688/

Answer (score 0):

A way of acomplishing what you want is to use [`iregex` field lookup](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#iregex).

First, get the tags you want. Instead of doing:

```
parent_document = Document.objects.get(id = 1)
parent_document_tags = [x.name for x in parent_document.documenttags_set.all()]
```

you can do:

```
parent_document_tags = DocumentTags.objects.filter(documents_for_tag=1).values_list("name",flat=True)
```

Secondly, you get a regular expression that behaves as you want. For example, suppose you have just one tag in `parent_document_tags` called "tag". If i understand what you want, you would like to match all documents that have tags that contains (icontains) this tag. So your query need to match documents tagged with "tag1" tag, "its_a_common_tag" tag... Am i right?

So, this is how you can create such a regular expression (a string with regex format):

```
sregex = "|".join(parent_document_tags)
sregex = "(" + sregex + ")"
```

Finally, the queryset you want would be like this:

```
Document.objects.filter(documenttags__name__iregex=sregex)
```

Regular expressions are great. It's difficult to start using them but when you understand how they work, you will earn a lot of effort.

Hope it helps!